# ThreadException - Event most of the time occurs on UI Thread but sometimes on another Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a method that gets an `Object` from network and then update the `UI` with this data.

I use third-party API to fetch data and also to receive the data.
The download process done in a new `Thread` and getting and updating the data done in `UI Thread`.

in my main Thread:

```
public void getNetRequest (DownloaderRequest netRequest) {
        carImage.setBackgroundResource(netRequest.imageResource);
    }
```

In 85% this code runs on UI thread, but sometimes in the 15% time I'm getting an exception :

```
    [DownloaderForRequests]android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6024)

.
.
.
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

When I debug it I see that `getNetRequest` called in the `Main Thread`, but the exception saying it was called on `DownloaderForRequests` `Thread`.
I added an log for checking the current thread and it showed that it's really not the Main Thread when this exception happened.

Why it is happening rarely and how can I test it and fix it for 100% ?
I don't want to use `runOnUiThread` because it wont be fixing the problem I want to detect it and understand the problem and not just adding more code without any reason.

Comment: We will need more code to help you.

Comment: It looks like you can use AsyncTask

Comment: Please provide (at least the threading related) code for DownloaderRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check for which thread, something like

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() != Thread.currentThread()) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    method();
                }
            });
        }else{
            method();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I want to understand why it happening in 15% of time, so I can fix it in other place too.